# При подгрузке html элементов через ajax перестает работать функция

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени! есть примерно такой html

```
<ul>
 <li class="hidafi">1
   <ul style='display: none;'>
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li>1.2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="hidafi">2
   <ul style='display: none;'>
     <li>2.1</li>
     <li>2.2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

и такие скрипты управляющие этими блоками

```
window.onload=function(){

$(".hidafi").click(function () { 
    $("#filtresse").children("li").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).children("ul").css('display','none');
    });
    $(this).children("ul").css('display','block');
});

$(".hidafi").children("ul").children("li").click(function (e) {     
    e.stopPropagation(); 


    $(this).parent("ul").css('display','none');
});


}
```

Так же блок html - иногда генерируется и заменяется через ajax - и после перезагрузки скрипт перестает работать, скажите почему? это что то связанное с DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для динамически создаваемых элементов, которых нет во время инициализации страницы и прикрепления обработчиков событий, используйте делегирование. Это, в то же время, работает и для уже существующих элементов.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click", ".hidafi", function () { ... });

$(document).on("click", ".hidafi ul li", function (e) { ... });
```

Comment: мне кажется у тебя была уже куча ответов на вопрос про события и динамические элементы, почему не закрыть как дубликат? :-)

Comment: @Igor  спасибо! я подозревал что что то подобное там, пару раз натыкался на похожие нюансы)

Comment: @Grundy кто-нибудь может объяснить мне, как искать среди своих ответов по ключевым словам?

Comment: @Grundy меня просто напугал информер в комментах того вопросса типа "не надо устраивать обсуждения в комментариях"

Comment: @Igor, например так: заходишь в профиль, сверху справа в окошке поиска будет твой id, дописываешь в окошко поиск - ищется по твоим постам: ответам/вопросам. Общий вид строки такой: `user:userId` далее текст который ищешь

Comment: @Grundy хм, спасибо, сейчас попробую